# View fill space if sibling is gone

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

So, I'm trying to get a `TextView` to fill the space left by a `ImageView` when it is `GONE`... I've tried using `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout`, but the ImageView's space isn't taken by the TextView.

So, how I get it to work?

Code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/cabecalho"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/imgPrimary"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_rating_star_on_mtrl_alpha"
        android:tint="#ecac31"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="3dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="17dp"
        android:text="Endereço de Teste"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgPrimary"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnEdit"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/addrTitle"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnDelete"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_write_location"
        android:tint="#08b8ae"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_clear_mtrl_alpha"
        android:tint="#d60d0d"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:padding="7dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Requested print:
[image: The space is to the right of the bold "Teste" at the top of the white card.]
The space is to the right of the bold "Teste" at the top of the white card.

Code from my recyclerview adapter:

```
public class AddrAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Address> addressList;

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public LinearLayout layout;

        public TextView titulo, enderecoCompleto;
        public ImageButton btnEdit, btnDelete;
        public ImageView isDefaultStar;
        //public RelativeLayout cabecalho;

        public ViewHolder(LinearLayout layout) {
            super(layout);
            this.layout = layout;

            this.titulo = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.addrTitle);
            this.enderecoCompleto = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.addrComplete);
            this.btnEdit = (ImageButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);
            this.btnDelete = (ImageButton) layout.findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
            this.isDefaultStar = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.imgPrimary);
            //this.cabecalho = (RelativeLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.cabecalho);
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolderHint extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView text;

        public ViewHolderHint(TextView text) {
            super(text);
            this.text = text;
        }
    }

    public AddrAdapter(List<Address> addresses) {
        this.addressList = addresses;
        if (addresses.size() > 0 && this.addressList.get(0).getCity() != null) {
            this.addressList.add(0, new Address());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        switch (viewType) {
            case 0 : {
                TextView v = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.card_address_hint, parent, false);

                ViewHolderHint vhh = new ViewHolderHint(v);
                return vhh;
            }
            default : {
                LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.card_address, parent, false);

                ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
                return vh;
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (position < 1) {
            ViewHolderHint hint = (ViewHolderHint) holder;
            hint.text.setText(Html.fromHtml("Selecione um <b>endereço de entrega</b>"));
        } else {
            final ViewHolder layout = (ViewHolder) holder;

            layout.isDefaultStar.setVisibility((addressList.get(position).getDefaultAddress()) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            //layout.cabecalho.requestLayout();
            layout.titulo.setText(addressList.get(position).getTitle());
            layout.enderecoCompleto.setText(
                    addressList.get(position).getDescription()+", "+
                            addressList.get(position).getNumber()+"\n"+
                            addressList.get(position).getComplement()+", "+
                            addressList.get(position).getNeighborhood()+" - "+
                            addressList.get(position).getCity().getName()+" - "+
                            addressList.get(position).getCity().getState().getCode()+"\n"+
                            addressList.get(position).getZipcode()
            );

            layout.btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int pos = layout.getAdapterPosition();
                    Address addr = addressList.get(pos);

                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putSerializable("ADDRESS_TO_EDIT",addr);
                    b.putInt("CHAVE_ENDERECO",pos); // TODO: Talvez no futuro seja a ID do endereço
                    Intent i = new Intent(AddressActivity.this,CheckoutAddressAddEditActivity.class);
                    i.putExtras(b);
                    startActivityForResult(i,006);
                }
            });

            layout.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int pos = layout.getAdapterPosition();

                    addresses.remove(pos);

                    notifyItemRemoved(pos);
                }
            });

            layout.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int pos = layout.getAdapterPosition();
                    Address addr = addressList.get(pos);

                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                    extras.putSerializable("ADDRESS", addr);
                    Intent data = new Intent();
                    data.putExtras(extras);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return addresses.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int pos) {
        return (pos > 0) ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your screens if thats not much trouble?

Comment: About which imageView you're talking? About first, `imgPrimary`?

Comment: @SergeyGlotov Yes...

Comment: Strange. Your code is working for me. 1. Are you sure you don't set visibility of imageView to invisible instead of gone somewhere? 2. What if you add `android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"` to textView?

Comment: @SergeyGlotov, I'm trying Smit Davda's answer, if it don't work, I will try your suggestion...

Comment: @SergeyGlotov I've tried your tip, but no go... I'm thinking it is a problem due to the layout being inside a recyclerView.

Comment: May be. Can you show recyclerView adapter code?

Comment: @SergeyGlotov added.

Answer (score 3):

The trick here is actually to NOT supply a weightSum.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:weightSum=3
    ...>
    <TextView
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="1">
```

Will print the three TextViews, evenly spaced as 1/3 of the available space each, whether the TextViews are View.GONE or not.

```
<LinearLayout
    ...>
    <TextView
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="1">
```

Will space the the TextViews as 1/3 of the space each, until one of them is View.GONE, at which point it will adjust to 1/2 space each.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a linear layout and provide a weightsum to the layout and weights to each of the views and also set the the width of each view to 0dp but do provide weights to each views. In that case if a view is gone its space will be taken by the other view

Comment: I tried, if you look at my code, you will see that there are weights that I didn't remove... Even if the imageview default is gone, it's space is not occupied by the textview...

Comment: you have used Relative Layout in your code. You need to use Linear Layout, set weightSum parameter to the layout and layout_weight to each view. Also set the width to 0 for each view

Comment: As before, it didn't work... I've set the weightSum, and the weights, but the space still blank... I checked on Android Device Monitor, and the ImageView is really gone, but it's space isn't occupied...

Comment: Did you set layout_width for all views to be 0 dp?

Comment: Yes, tried both all widths as 0dp, and just the textview with 0dp width... On the former all views are equally scrambled (and there is still a space for the first imageview that is gone, and on the later I get the same result as all the tests...